# wampserver was unable to start correctly. click ok to close error in windows 10. in wamp server

Tags: wampserver

Error Screenshot :

[image]

Help Me For This Problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Comment: Read the [Troubleshooting tips](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915) on the WAMPServer forum.  Most likely point 20 as it sounds like you have not got all the required MSVC Runtimes installed